# Logistic regression model that has one categorical variable with multiple values

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data

I have the following data:

```
Rank    Platforms        Technology

high    Windows||Linux   Unity
high    Linux             
low     Windows          Unreal 
low     Linux||MacOs     GameMakerStudio||Unity||Unreal
low                      GameMakerStudio
```

Both `Platforms` and `Technology` are categorical variables and each row can have one, or multiple, or Empty value.

How do I go about building a logistic regression model that predict the `Rank`  as `high` or `low` in R?

I am thinking to separate the variable into multiple Boolean variables: like `is_windows = [true, false]`, `is_mac = [true, false]`,etc... However, for `Technology`, there are about 21 unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Use One Hot Encoding. Here a link to [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/). It's in `python`, but you should get the idea. It's pretty basic stuff, so I guess it should be available in some `R` package.

Comment: Hi @Piotr Rarus, that works for variable that has one value a time. Not multiple values

Comment: Not really. Consider technologies: `GameMakerStudio`, `Unity`, `Unreal`. Our record has all these values, so you just code it as `[1, 1, 1]`. You must be mistaking it for label encoding.

Comment: could you post a full working example? Thank you

Comment: Check [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)